# Flutter: NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'Global.models.<anonymous closure>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building my own flutter app with the help of the Flutter Firebase course from [fireship.io](https://fireship.io).
The courses repository is [here](https://github.com/fireship-io/flutter-firebase-quizapp-course).

However, since abandoning multiple streams - from my own tries before starting the course - in favor of classes with anonymous types, I receive the following error message and can't get my head around why.

**Goal:**
I want a Stream with all documents from any firestore collection, in this case 'hochschulen'. The Collection exists and is filled with data. All fields are Strings.

**Expected:**
No error message

**Actual Result:**

```
flutter: The following assertion was thrown:
flutter: An exception was throw by _MapStream<QuerySnapshot, List<University>> listened by
flutter: StreamProvider<List<University>>, but no `catchError` was provided.
flutter:
flutter: Exception:
flutter: NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'Global.models.<anonymous
flutter: closure>'
flutter: Receiver: Closure: (dynamic, String) => University
flutter: Tried calling: Global.models.<anonymous closure>(data: _LinkedHashMap len:10)
flutter: Found: Global.models.<anonymous closure>(dynamic, String) => University
flutter:
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

**I have tried:**

- defining all expected types of all parameters
- I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59007248/closure-call-with-mismatched-arguments-but-i-cant-figure-out-why) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804542/closure-call-with-mismatched-arguments-function-mylistview-functionone) and some more similar questions, but struggle to adapt to my code, because I can't find missing parameters.
- I do believe I understand that this issue probably occures because some type and/or parameter of something is mixed up or missing.

**This is the widget where I want to load some data:**

```
class LegalScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<University>>.value(
      value: Global.universityRef.streamData(),
      child: LegalScreenContent(),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is my global class:**

```
class Global {
  static final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
  static final Map models = {
    // Dish: (data, id) => Dish.fromMap(data, id),
    // Event: (data, id) => Event.fromMap(data, id),
    // News: (data, id) => News.fromMap(data, id),
    // Subject: (data, id) => Subject.fromMap(data, id),
    University: ({Map data}) => University.fromMap(data: data),
    // UserModel: (data, id) => UserModel.fromMap(data, id),
  };
  static final UserData<UserModel> userModelRef =
      UserData<UserModel>(collection: 'users');
  static final Collection<University> universityRef =
      Collection<University>(path: 'hochschulen');
}
```

**Here is the model for University:**

```
class University {
  String city;
  String domain;
  String mail;
  String name;
  String shortName;
  String street;
  String phone;
  String website;
  String zip;
  University(
      {this.city,
      this.domain,
      this.mail,
      this.name,
      this.shortName,
      this.street,
      this.phone,
      this.website,
      this.zip});
  University.fromMap({Map data}) {
    city = data['city'] ?? '';
    domain = data['domain'] ?? '';
    mail = data['mail'] ?? '';
    name = data['name'] ?? '';
    shortName = data['short_name'] ?? '';
    street = data['street'] ?? '';
    phone = data['tel'] ?? '';
    website = data['website'] ?? '';
    zip = data['zip'] ?? '';
  }
}
```

**Here is my Collection class:**

```
class Collection<T> {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final String path;
  CollectionReference ref;
  Collection({this.path}) {
    ref = _db.collection(path);
  }
  Future<List<T>> getData() async {
    var snapshots = await ref.get();
    return snapshots.docs
        .map((doc) => Global.models[T](doc.data, doc.id) as T)
        .toList();
  }
  Stream<List<T>> streamData() {
    return ref.snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Global.models[T](data: doc.data()) as T)
        .toList());
  }
}
```

Comment: did u get the answer anyway, i was also looking for it!

Comment: Check your variable names and then reboot your system as well as uninstalling the app from the emulator and running flutter clean and flutter run. Then the error was gone for me. It is some weird caching with hot reload Or something I guess.

Comment: Thankyou, but in my case the proplem was with a function containing setState